# Exporting OBIEE Dashboard page to Excel

Tags: export-to-excel, oracle12c, obiee

When exporting a dashboard page to excel, using the export to excel button, the page is displayed in multiple pages in excel.

How can the exported page display in a single page in excel?

Answer (score 0):

Add a text control with HTML layout to your dashboard, and paste the below definitions into the control:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function ExportXLS()
{ 
saw.dashboard.exportToExcel('/shared/Folder Path/','Report Name', true); 
} 
</script>
<a href=# OnClick='javascript:ExportXLS();'>Export To Excel</a>
```